# Get-Content fails to read path retrieved via WMI

Tags: powershell

```psh
gc "C:\folder1\folder2\MyService.exe.config"
```

All good

```psh
gwmi win32_service|?{$_.name -match "MyService"} | % {$_.pathname}
"C:\folder1\folder2\MyService.exe.config"
```

Returns correct path

```psh
gwmi win32_service|?{$_.name -match "Mailing"} | % {$_.pathname} | % {$_.gettype()}
```

Return type is definitely a string

```psh
gwmi win32_service|?{$_.name -match "Mailing"} | % {$_.pathname} | % {gc -path $_}
```

```
gc : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '"C' does not exist.
At line:1 char:71
+ gwmi win32_service|?{$_.name -match "MyService"} | % {$_.pathname} | % {gc -path $ ...
+                                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ("C:String) [Get-Content], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you want to do here? the returned pathname is most likely an exe file, why do you want retrieve the content of it in powershell? Anyways, try this: gwmi win32_service|?{$_.name -match "IDLSemanticLogging"} | select -ExpandProperty Pathname | % { gc $_}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a closer look at the error message:

```
A drive with the name '"C' does not exist.
                       ^
```

Note the `"` in front of the drive letter.

The path returned from the WMI query is between double quotes, i.e. the double quotes are not *delimiting the string* as in your first statement, but are *part of the string*, so `Get-Content` fails, because it can't find a drive `"C:`.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $path = "C:\temp\web.config"
PS C:\> $path
C:\temp\web.config
PS C:\> Get-Content $path
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
...
</configuration>
PS C:\> $path = '"C:\temp\web.config"'
PS C:\> $path
"C:\temp\web.config"
PS C:\> Get-Content $path
Get-Content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '"C' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Content $path
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ("C:String) [Get-Content], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Remove the double quotes from beginning and end of the string and the problem will disappear:

```bsh
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match "Mailing" } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.PathName -replace '^"(.*)"$', '$1' } |
    ForEach-Object { Get-Content -Path $_ }
```